# Flatten nested xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, nested, flatten

I am facing challenging to flatten a nested xml file using xslt.

**Input xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group xmlns="http://group.com/group">
    <sub-group>
        <group-name>group1</group-name>
        <group-parameter1>
            <group-parameter11>param11</group-parameter11>
            <group-parameter21>param21</group-parameter21>
        </group-parameter1>
        <group-parameter2>
            <group-parameter21>param21</group-parameter21>
        </group-parameter2>
    </sub-group>
    <sub-group>
        <group-name>group2</group-name>
        <group-parameter1>
            <group-parameter11>param11</group-parameter11>
            <group-parameter21>param21</group-parameter21>
        </group-parameter1>
        <group-parameter3>
            <group-parameter31>param31</group-parameter31>
        </group-parameter3>
    </sub-group>
</group>
```

**Expected output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group xmlns="http://group.com/group">
    <sub-group>
        <group-name>group1</group-name>
        <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11 xmlns="">param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
        <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
        <sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21>
    </sub-group>
    <sub-group>
        <group-name>group2</group-name>
        <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11 xmlns="">param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
        <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
        <sub-group.group-parameter3.group-parameter31 xmlns="">param31</sub-group.group-parameter3.group-parameter31>
    </sub-group>
</group>
```

If I use the below xslt file to transform the input xml, it does not provide the expected output:
**xsl file:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
    <xsl:mode streamable="no"/>
    
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::*[not(*)]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:element name="{string-join(ancestor::*[position() lt last()]/name(), '.')}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output using the above xsl file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group xmlns="http://group.com/group">
   <sub-group.group-name xmlns="">group1</sub-group.group-name>
   <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11 xmlns="">param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
   <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
   <sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21>
   <sub-group.group-name xmlns="">group2</sub-group.group-name>
   <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11 xmlns="">param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
   <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
   <sub-group.group-parameter3.group-parameter31 xmlns="">param31</sub-group.group-parameter3.group-parameter31>
</group>
```

Any idea on how to fix this. By the way, I want to use a general code so that it can be used for other type of input file as well.

Regards,
Ashish

Comment: FYI- ultimate objective is to convert the input xml data to panda dataframe that will have two rows having group1 and group2.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following solution.

It is using a so called *Identity Transform* pattern.

[XSLT Fiddle](https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/eixh2xx)

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<group xmlns="http://group.com/group">
    <sub-group>
        <group-name>group1</group-name>
        <group-parameter1>
            <group-parameter11>param11</group-parameter11>
            <group-parameter21>param21</group-parameter21>
        </group-parameter1>
        <group-parameter2>
            <group-parameter21>param21</group-parameter21>
        </group-parameter2>
    </sub-group>
    <sub-group>
        <group-name>group2</group-name>
        <group-parameter1>
            <group-parameter11>param11</group-parameter11>
            <group-parameter21>param21</group-parameter21>
        </group-parameter1>
        <group-parameter3>
            <group-parameter31>param31</group-parameter31>
        </group-parameter3>
    </sub-group>
</group>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xpath-default-namespace="http://group.com/group"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
   <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

   <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:template match="sub-group/*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'group-parameter')]">
        <xsl:for-each select="./*">
            <xsl:element name="{string-join((ancestor::*[position() lt last()]/local-name(), local-name()), '.')}" namespace="http://group.com/group">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<group xmlns="http://group.com/group">
  <sub-group>
    <group-name>group1</group-name>
    <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
    <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
    <sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21>param21</sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21>
  </sub-group>
  <sub-group>
    <group-name>group2</group-name>
    <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
    <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
    <sub-group.group-parameter3.group-parameter31>param31</sub-group.group-parameter3.group-parameter31>
  </sub-group>
</group>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks! but I am getting xmlns=""  in the output too. Can we suppress those?

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<group xmlns="http://group.com/group">
   <sub-group>
      <group-name>group1</group-name>
      <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11 xmlns="">param11</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11>
      <sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter21>
      <sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21 xmlns="">param21</sub-group.group-parameter2.group-parameter21>
   </sub-group>

Comment: I am using Saxon, and not getting any empty default namespaces. What processor you are using?

Comment: I am using VS code with this addon - https://deltaxml.github.io/vscode-xslt-xpath/

Comment: Is it XSLT 3.0 conformant processor?

Comment: `<xsl:element name="{string-join((ancestor::*[position() lt last()]/local-name(), local-name()), '.')}" namespace="http://group.com/group">` needs to be used to put the element constructed with `xsl:element` into that particular namespace. Or an `xmlns="http://group.com/group"` higher up in the stylesheet document e.g. on the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: But I am not sure I understand @Ashish, as the wanted output does have e.g. `sub-group.group-parameter1.group-parameter11 xmlns=""` so if the XSLT posted produces that it seems to do what is asked.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, I updated the answer based on your input. Thanks. And added XSLT Fiddle.